# is it possible to control the speed of .attr?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if you can control the speed of `.attr` function:

```
$("#div1").hover(function() {
  $("#div1 img").attr('src','images/image01.png');
```

Comment: what does that even mean?

Comment: Speed? Animation? Transition? What?

Comment: Probably want's to fade the new image in or something.

Comment: You could call a `setTimeout` and defer the `attr` if you want to slow it down. Good luck speeding it up, though...

Comment: very curious about your requirement

Comment: @jamie I want the image to appear with fadein effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the image to fade in you need to use jQuery's `.fadeIn` effect.

You first hide the image

```
<div id='div1'>
  <img style='display:none;' src=''/>
```

And then you run the fadeIn effect on it:

```
$("#div1").hover(function() {
  $("#div1 img").attr('src','images/image01.png');
  $("#div1 img").fadeIn(200); // 200 is transition time in millisecond
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout)

```
$("#div1").hover(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'images/image01.png').fadeIn();
    }, 1000); //1second
});
```

This will change the `src` of the image after one second.

Comment: Notice that there would be a problem with `this` context in your code.

Comment: thanks. but I want the image to fade in. is it possible with .attr?

Comment: Then you can use .fadeIn() at the end after attr @KcLee